# Календарь - время - по дефолту нулевое значение

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как у этого календаря: [JSCal2](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) сделать время не текущее, а 00:00 ?
Спасибо.

Comment: Так не получается
h=a.getHours(0),i=h>=12,j=i?h-12:h,k=N(a),l=a.getMinutes(0)

Comment: Что еще за getHours(0)? И что вообще за ужасти вы пишете? При загрузке страницы сделайте a.setTime(0).

Comment: Не совсем понял где воткнуть это? до подключения файлу с кодом JS?

Comment: Сразу после показа календаря.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.....

======


    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date1",
        trigger    : "f_date1",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 24,
        dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
      });
   
   a.setTime(0);

    //]]></script>

Comment: Добавьте в setup `time: 0`.

Comment: По прежнему все


    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date1",
        trigger    : "f_date1",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 24,
 setupTime  : 0,
        dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
      });
   
   a.setTime(0);
   

так вообще календарь пропадает
setup еime  : 0,

Comment: Эхх...

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date1",
        trigger    : "f_date1",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 24,
        time  : 0,
        dateFormat : "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
      });

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот таким хуком

> dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d 00:00"

в самом календарике время будет текущее, но при клике на день в поле будет вставляться **2011-11-28 00:00**